# Stack around the variable was corrupted when using code from library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stack, corruption, log4cplus

I'm using log4cplus library. When I build application, it compiles and runs properly (well, not quite properly since it's not logging anything, but that's the other issue), but when I close it, I'm getting this error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 's1' was corrupted.
```

Here is my code. I marked relevant places with comments.

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       _In_ int       nCmdShow) {
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    ////////////////// SET UP CHECKS FOR MEMORY LEAKS ////////////////////
    _CrtMemState s1;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator config(_T("log.properties")); // <-- this line seems to be responsible for the issue. When I remove it, everything is ok.

    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&s1); // <-- here program breaks with mentioned error.

    return 1;
}
```

So, as written in comments, `PropertyConfigurator()` constructor seems to be responsible for the problem. Not any other code in this place causes the same problem.

I wonder what could be wrong if this library is used by many people and it works, while I have problems with stack corruption.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on in here?

**EDIT:**

I removed all unnecessary code (the code above is edited) and left only the relevant. Still `log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator config(_T("log.properties"));` seems to cause the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `// Some not relevant OpenGL stuff goes here...` is not the culprit instead?

Comment: Also, you do not say what version of log4cplus is that?

Comment: @wilx the version is 1.1.1

Comment: @wilx I'm sure it's not the culprit, because when I comment it out and leave only the code I presented, the issue is still there.

Comment: Alright. Please test whether 1.1.2-RC2 does not fix your problem. There is at least [one bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/bugs/163/) in 1.1.1 that is fixed in 1.1.2-RC2.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try it today and will let you know.

Comment: @wilx Unfortunately the new version doesn't help. Still the same issue.

Comment: Does it help to call `log4cplus::initialize()` before doing anything else log4cplus related?

Comment: @wilx Still the same...

Comment: @wilx Well, this is funny, because when I try with: `PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure(_T("log.properties"));` everything is fine. I guess there shouldn't be any difference, as when I look into the source code, `doConfigure()` is creating a temp `PropertyConfigurator` object using the same constructor anyway... am I right?

Answer (score 1):

This error `Run-Time Check Failure #2` is generally caused by an error somewhere in memory. After looking at the sample you provided you should change this:

`log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator config(_T("log.properties"));`

to this:

```
log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator configure(_T("log.properties"));
```

If that does not help then start looking at initializations of memory.